# Switch-Case don't work like this?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am trying to convert a JavaScript switch to a C# one.

I am getting error `Error   3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'int'`

```
        switch (numero)
        {
            case (numero > -1 && numero < 16):
                rtn = list1[numero] + " " + str2;
                if (primerDigito != 1)
                {
                    rtn += "s";
                }
                break;
            case (numero > 15 && numero < 30):
                if (numero != 20)
                {
                    rtn = list2[primerDigito] + list1[segundoDigito];
                }
                else
                {
                    rtn = "veinte";
                }
                rtn += " " + str2 + "s";
                break;
            case (numero > 29 && numero < 100):
                rtn = list2[primerDigito] + "nta";
                if (segundoDigito != 0)
                {
                    rtn += " y " + list1[segundoDigito];
                }
                rtn += " " + str2 + "s";
                break;
            case 100:
                rtn = "cien " + str2 + "s";
                break;
            default:
                rtn = "número invalido";
        }
```

Is there a work around for this?

**Note:** I really MUST use switch-case (and not if-elses)

Comment: You're going to have to explain that **Note**, you know.

Comment: Why *must* you?  That's not how case statements work in C#.

Comment: Seriously?, I MUST explain my MUST or I get downvoted?. Okey, an angry bear said that if I don't, he will come to my house and eat me...

Comment: Once I had a homework that explicitly stated the use `switch-case` instead of `if-else` where it was almost impossible to use. It turned out the teacher was messing with us. I suspect this is homework?

Comment: If it is homework, the correct answer is still `if`/`else`

Comment: @mithril333221 The reason an explanation is warranted is so that you can get answers either working within your constraints or giving you suggestions for approaches you may not have tried.

Comment: You might enjoy [Why do people question every question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108060/why-do-people-question-every-question), in particular the highest-voted answer, which is much better than my own effort.

Comment: @AtoMerZ I will just do the switches with if-elses and store in `cases= (1, 2 or 3)` then use the switch-case with this new variable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot do this: a `switch` statement can only use single values, not ranges for the `case`s.

You need an `if`/`else` tree instead. Something in the form of:

```
if(numero > -1 && numero < 16) {
 rtn = list1[numero] + " " + str2;
 if (primerDigito != 1)
 {
  rtn += "s";
 }
} else if(numero > 15 && numero < 30) {
 // logic in second block
} else if...
```

Note that if you're **absolutely, totally committed** to using a `switch`, you would have to enumerate all of the cases (but this is such an egregious sin against software engineering that I can't even believe I'm writing it out - *do not do this, it's just an example of how switch statements work*):

```
switch(numero)
{
 case 0:
 case 1:
 case 2:
 case 3:
 case 4:
 case 5:
 case 6:
 case 7:
 case 8:
 case 9:
 case 10:
 case 11:
 case 12:
 case 13:
 case 14:
 case 15:
  rtn = list1[numero] + " " + str2;
  if (primerDigito != 1)
  {
   rtn += "s";
  }
  break;
 case 16:
 ...
 case 28:
 case 29:
  // second logic block
  break;
 ...
}
```

If I saw this in my codebase, though, I would be baffled and angry.

Comment: +1 This is really how the problem has to be solved. It's bizarre that the OP is insisting it be `switch` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The answer, although not the one you want, is that you have to use compile-time constants in your `case` expressions. If the expression will vary at run-time then you **must** use `if..else` instead.

In addition, the `case` value is an implicit logical equality comparison and can't make use of `<` or `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this isn't how `switch`/`case` works. `if`/`else if` is the right thing to do.

You can stack `case`s as shown below, but when you have this many `case`s it is NOT the right thing to do.

```
switch(numero)
{
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
                and so on
    case 15:
        code here
        break;
    case 16:
    case 17:
                and so on
    case 29:
        code here
        break;
                and so on
    case 100:
        rtn = "cien " + str2 + "s"; 
        break;  
    default:      
        rtn = "número invalido";  
 }
```

Comment: Bleh, yeah. I think i'll remove this in a bit in favour of Mr. "baffled and angry".

Answer (score 0):

This is (mostly) not possible without using an if-else. If you MUST use a switch, then this is the only way I know of (letting the cases drop down to each other):

```
switch (numero)
{
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    ...
    case 15:
        //Do Stuff
        break;
    case 16:
    ...
    //Continue as above for each range
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no ranges support in switch statements, you can either use if else statements or you can do this:

```
  case 15:
  case 16:
  case 16:
  case 18: 
// do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are entirely correct.  Switch statements in C# dont work like that.

The correct way to implement such logic in C# is to use an if, else if, else block. (Yes I have seen your note but am unsure why you must use a switch).

For various design reasons switch statements and if else chains are discouraged because by their very definition they have X behaviours or responsibilities.   A better approach is to try for a solution that uses [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).   You should aim to refactor these behaviours into separate distinct classes that each handle one of the cases.